# Are WDDM 1.2 drivers backward compatible with WDDM 1.0?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-vista, drivers

WDDM 1.1 drivers are backward compatible with WDDM 1.0 specification; both 1.0 and 1.1 drivers can be used in Windows Vista.

Can WDDM 1.2 also be used in Windows Vista?

Comment: AFAIK it's not completely backwards compatible. However I don't see how the theory helps you, since you've practically tried Win7/8 drivers in Vista and it did not work on your laptop.

Answer (score 1):

AMDs Catalyst drivers also work in Vista, so WDDM1.2 is also backwards compatible:

> **Compatible Operating Systems**
>
> The latest version of the AMD Catalyst software suite is designed to
>   support the following Microsoft Windows platforms:
>
> ```
> Windows 8 32-bit version
> Windows 8 64-bit version
> Windows 7 32-bit version SP1 or higher
> Windows 7 64-bit version SP1 or higher
> ```
>
> **>     Windows Vista 32-bit version SP2 or higher
>       Windows Vista 64-bit version SP2 or higher**

http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalystSoftwareSuiteVersion131.aspx